# AngularJS Directives: Are Link and Compile functions meant to work together?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a few doubts about this functions.

Lets say I have this directive:

```
.directive('hello', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div>Hello <span ng-transclude></span></div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude: true,
      compile: function() {
        console.log('Compile()');

        return {
          pre: function() {
            console.log('PreLink()');
          },
          post: function() {
            console.log('PostLink()');
          }
        };
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
        console.log('Link()');
      }
    };
  }
```

And I add it to my template as:

```
<hello>World</hello>
```

The console logs:

```
Compile()
PreLink()
PostLink()
```

So why is the `link()` not being called?

If instead of returning an object from `compile()` I return a single function printing `PreLink()` the console logs:

```
Compile()
PreLink()
```

If I don't return anything from `Compile()` the console logs:

```
Compile()
```

Still `link()` is not being called.

If I just comment `Compile()` then `Link()` is finally printed:

```
Link()
```

Can someone explain all this? Are `Link()` and `Compile()` mean to work together? Should I just use Compile's `PreLink()` and `PostLink()`?

Comment: This stackoverflow post almost nailed it. Pls refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`link` and `compile` do not work together, no.

In the directive definition object, if you **only** define `link`, that's like shorthand for having an empty `compile` function with an empty `preLink` function with your code in the `postLink` function. As soon as you define `compile`, `link` is ignored by angular, because compile should return the linking functions.

If you only return one function from `compile`, then it'll be executed **post** link.

Or, put differently, `link` is just a shortcut to the `postLink` function that gets called after the scope has been linked by `compile`.

It's (sort of) documented [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile) - look at the comments in the code sample.

Comment: "because compile should return the linking functions" -- exactly the info I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

A couple of days ago a nice article has been published by Jurgen Van de Moere on "The nitty-gritty of compile and link functions inside AngularJS directives". It explains quite clearly on the responsibilities and sequence of the `compile`, `pre-link` and `post-link` functions.

[image]
<sub>(source: [jvandemo.com](http://www.jvandemo.com/content/images/2014/Aug/cycle-2.png))</sub>

You should definitely check it out: http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives