# AngularJS : Determine when rendered inner directives exist

Tags: angularjs, events, render, directive

Inside one of my views I'm using `myDirective` like this:

```
<div my-directive></div>
```

It (`myDirective`) has a template:

```
<div>
    <div my-inner-directive></div>
</div>
```

My question is: how do I know from within `myDirective` that all sub-directives were rendered? In essence, when can I use `element.find()` and actually get results? DO NOT offer me `window.setTimeout` and `$timeout` because those are bogus solutions that will never work properly.

Comment: sound like bad idea... u can do smth like <div my-inner-directive afterRender="afterRender()"></div> and launch afterRender() manually from i.e. link of my-inner-directive

Comment: In reality, I have a search directive that has my custom text box and button directives. What's so bad about that?

Comment: i.e. temaplte of my-directive: <customtextbox value="value"/><custombutton1 ng-click="search"/><custombutton2 ng-click="smth"/> So why u need to use element.find()?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this markup..

```
<parent>
    <child1>
        <child2></child2>
    </child1>
</parent>
```

The order of execution is:

1. PreLinking of Parent
2. PreLinking of Child1
3. PreLinking of Child2
4. PostLinking of Child2
5. PostLinking of Child1
6. PostLinking of Parent.

PostLinking function of a directive will guarantee the execution of its child elements.

It is place to bind event listeners or lookup for child DOM nodes.

In the markup that is specified in the example.. 
`PostLinking of myDirective will be executed after myInnerDirective is compiled.`

More on this at: [link](http://www.jvandemo.com/the-nitty-gritty-of-compile-and-link-functions-inside-angularjs-directives/)

Comment: I kinda don't understand. Can you give an example code?

Comment: Updated the post. Please have a look at the link that i have given.

Answer (score 1):

Vinay K gave you a good link but you should also take a look at this post on StackOverflow: [Angular directives - when and how to use compile, controller, pre-link and post-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post)

It's quite long but has probably most of the stuff you'll need to know for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out that I was doing some things the wrong way. I have also missed that I can use `$broadcast()` and `$on()`.

So. Inner directive:

```
$scope.$broadcast('myCustomDirectiveEvent')
```

Outer/parent directive:

```
$scope.$on('myCustomDirectiveEvent')
```