# Compile and add directive dynamically in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

What does the $compile function do and how can we use it to add a directive dynamically via js code?

Does anyone have fully functioning code samples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post

Answer (score 0):

Thought it will help a lot of developers out there to get something fully functioning on this. Here's a sample answer.

The $compile service compiles the fragment of html(`<test text="n"></test>`) that includes the directive("test" as an element) and produces a function. This function can then be executed with a scope to get the "html output from a directive".

```
var compileFunction = $compile("<test text="n"></test>");
var HtmlOutputFromDirective = compileFunction($scope);
```

More details with full code samples here: 
http://www.learn-angularjs-apps-projects.com/AngularJs/dynamically-add-directives-in-angularjs