# What is the difference between using the link attribute vs using compile with pre-link and post-link?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post) is pretty informative about pre-link and post-link using the compile attribute in a directive definition. However, it doesn't say anything about what it means to just straight up use the link attribute. I'm talking about the difference between these two things:

A:

```
myApp.directive('log', function() {
    return {
      link: function(...){...},
      // other stuff here
    };
});
```

B.

```
myApp.directive('log', function() {  
    return {  
      compile: function(...){
          return {
            pre: function preLink( scope, element, attributes ) {
               // stuff
            },
            post: function postLink( scope, element, attributes ) {
                // stuff
            }
          }
      },  
      // other stuff here  
    };  
});
```

What is a `link` function? Is it supposed to combine pre and post? I do not understand how to use these two patterns differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no functional difference - just API "sugar":

```
link: function postlink(){...}
```

is an API shortcut for:

```
link: {
  post: function postlink(){...}
}
```

which, in its full form is:

```
link: {
  pre: function prelink(){...},
  post: function postlink(){...}
}
```

which, on its own, is a shortcut of

```
compile: function(){
  return {
     pre: function prelink(){...},
     post: function postlink(){...}
  };
}
```

which, could be slightly simplified to:

```
compile: function(){
  return function postlink(){...}
}
```

When `compile` property is specified, `link` property is ignored.

Here's Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#comprehensive-directive-api) on the subject

Comment: holy christ that's a lot of equivalences