# Running angular custom directive when model gets loaded via $resource

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following problem with angular custom directives. I have a modal dialog that gets filled with input elements. These input elements get filled using ng-repeat angular directive like this

```
            <div ng-repeat="item in params">
                <label>{{item.nombre}}{{item.valor}}</label>
                <div class="input-group" ng-if="item.tipo=='DATE'">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
                    <input  type="text" name="{{item.nombre}}" class="form-control reportesFechas" ng-model="item.valor"
                            data-custom-datepicker data-date-format="dd/mm/yy" id="{{item.nombre}}">
                </div>
            </div>
```

**data-custom-datepicker** is my custom attribute. The **params** model gets filled via a service call to a java backend like this

```
         appbsReportsParamsService.query({
            q: "idReport="+id
        }, function(data){
            $scope.params = data.content;
        })
```

The service call works OK because the final HTML is "correct" in terms of inputs gets generated. However **data-custom-datepicker** doesn't get applied. 
This is the HTML "ng-repeat" portion being generated:

```
<div class="input-group ng-scope" ng-if="item.tipo=='DATE'">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
    <input type="text" name="fecDesde" class="form-control reportesFechas hasDatepicker ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="item.valor" data-custom-datepicker="" data-date-format="dd/mm/yy" id="fecDesde">
</div>
<div class="input-group ng-scope" ng-if="item.tipo=='DATE'">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span></span>
    <input type="text" name="fecHasta" class="form-control reportesFechas hasDatepicker ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="item.valor" data-custom-datepicker="" data-date-format="dd/mm/yy" id="fecHasta">
</div>
```

So basically I want to know how to apply the directive after a async service call to populate the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was I was running the directive code under "compile" phase. I change it to "post" phase, now everything works ok. The problem is the Angular workflow (not the problem, but where my misconception was). This post helped me understand.

[Angular directives - when and how to use compile, controller, pre-link and post-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding $scope.$apply() in your service success call after $scope.params = data.content.

Because your params service query is running outside of the $scope in Angular, doing the $apply, will force update the $scope.

See if that helps.

```
appbsReportsParamsService.query({
  q: "idReport="+id
}, function(data){
  $scope.params = data.content;
  $scope.$apply();
});
```