# How to get reference to element before directive replaces it with template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I get the data in HTML format. (because we use content mgmt). My task is to write a directive to parse this data into javascript object and then use template to display properly.

My problem is, when inside `link` method, the template is getting replaced, before I can operate on this HTML data.

**My HTML content**

```html
<body>
<div ci-course-calendar>
    <div class="ci-course-calendar-item">
        <div class="ci-course-calendar-item-title">Title</div>
        <div class="ci-course-calendar-item-summary">Summary</div>
        <div class="ci-course-calendar-item-date">Jan 21, 2016</div>
    </div>
   <div class="ci-course-calendar-item">
        <div class="ci-course-calendar-item-title">Title</div>
        <div class="ci-course-calendar-item-summary">Summary</div>
        <div class="ci-course-calendar-item-date">Jan 21, 2016</div>
    </div>
<div>
</body>
```

**My template of the directive - `ci-course-calendar`**

```
<div class="accordion">
   <div ng-repeat="course in courses">
       <!--do  something-->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that you need to use `compile` function instead of `link`. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post

Comment: @MoshFeu , looks like the compile function executes only once for a directive, but I need to parse this data each time the directive is used..  The link you shared was useful...but still confused, what needs to be used.

Comment: Are those div's inside of `ci-course-calendar` hard coded by you? Can't you just grab these values inside of your controller with `ng-model`? After that you can pass these values to you directive through the isolated scope?

Comment: @peter  these values comes from CQ5(content mgmt), so I need to parse this inside directive and then use it appropriately in template.