# Angular form $pristine is set to false by default

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-directive, bootstrap-datepicker

[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/nVct6k5F57SiADB2qKx3?p=preview) of my usecase.

I am using [Eternicode's Bootstrap Datepicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker) in my app. I have created a datepicker directive and same is used in Angular form.

**Datepicker directive :**

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
      .directive('myDatePicker', function($compile) {
        return {
          restrict: 'A',
          require: 'ngModel',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            $(element[0]).datepicker({
              autoclose: true,
              format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
            });

            $(element[0]).datepicker().on("change", function(e) {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(element.val());
              });
            });
          }
        };
      });
```

When the Angular form is initially loaded, following are its properties:

```
$pristine : false
$dirty : true
```

When i `watch` the `form model` and print them on console, i understood form model had property that was set by datepicker and this is how it looks :

[image]

On same [Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/nVct6k5F57SiADB2qKx3?p=preview) , if i comment date section in form following are its properties:

```
$pristine : true
$dirty : false
```

This is how `form model` looks now :

[image]

How do i keep my form model free from being corrupted, which is causing problems by setting $pristine to false and $dirty to true, despite of using Date directive ?

**PS : This is the abstraction of the bigger use-case that is in our current application.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have investigated you code and observed that, you should write you following code in compile function of directive.

```
 $(element[0]).datepicker({
          autoclose: true,
          format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
 });
```

it will resolve your problem.

so your directive looks like as follow :

```
    .directive('myDatePicker', function($compile) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      compile: function(scope,  element, attrs) {
        $(element[0]).datepicker({
          autoclose: true,
          format: "dd/mm/yyyy"
        });
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        $(element[0]).datepicker().on("change", function(e) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(element.val());
          });
        });
      }
    };
```

The compile function deals with transforming the template DOM. Since most directives do not do template transformation, it is not used often.

Comment: That worked like a charm man :) Time for me to read, re-read this [SOF link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103)

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your use case, but *after* you set your date selection, why don't you just do a programmatic

```
$scope.form.$setPristine();
```

I believe this was introduced in v1.1

Comment: i tried that but failed. Where do i do that ? In controller or in directive ?

Comment: Wherever your form is in scope. One way to see this would be to install batarang, and check your scopes. Whichever scope has `.form` should be where you use this