# How to avoid a subform to make outer form $dirty in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

Forms in AngularJS sometimes can become a bit ugly. That's my case. I have seemingly simple structure of three forms. Two of them should be related to each other, while third should be completely separate.

```
<form name="foo">
   <div ng-repeat="f in foo.list">
      <custom-component ng-form="foo['f_'+$index+'_something']"></custom-component>
   </div>
</form>
```

Above is main form. It binds some part of itself to custom component.

The component on the other hand has two forms inside:

```
<div ng-form="$ctrl.form">
   <!--foo-->
</div>
<some-popup>
   <div ng-form="$ctrl.popupForm">
      <!--foo-->
   </div >
</some-popup>
```

The problem is that `popupForm` is somehow automatically bound with other forms. The result is far from expectations. When I modify `popupForm` it makes item on `foo` form dirty. Moreover if some field on `popupForm` doesn't meet validation criteria, and popup is closed then error is propagated to the `foo` form's item. The latest problem can be solved with `ng-if` directive used to "remove" `popupForm`from DOM when popup is hidden, but it still not complete solution.

It there any way to make a form (`popupForm` of the example) completely separate from other? Can I prevent nesting forms somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is more complicated. As was mentioned before HTML standard doesn't allow `<form>` nesting - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form - *Permitted content*.

If you are not plan to cross-validate this `<div ng-form="$ctrl.popupForm">` with `<div ng-form="$ctrl.form">` usually this should be done by attach/append `popup` element do different *DOM* element.

For example `angular-ui` components *Bootstrap Modal* https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ have property called `appendTo`. This should solve `<form>` inheritance issue if you are using modals like Bootrstrap or Material Design http://mseemann.io/frontend/2016/10/10/angular-2-mdl-mdl-dialog-advanced-configuration.html .

More *hacky* alternatives involve creating custom `directive` and attach element using https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile `compile` functions. [Angular directives - when and how to use compile, controller, pre-link and post-link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615103/angular-directives-when-and-how-to-use-compile-controller-pre-link-and-post)

If you plan to have cross-validation, this should be solved with `service`/`provider` for communication and testability.

Answer (score 1):

The [`$removeControl` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$removeControl) can be used to remove a child form from its parent.

> ### $removeControl(control);
>
> Deregister a control from the form.
>
> Input elements using [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) do this automatically when they are destroyed.
>
> [— AngularJS Form Controller API Reference (`$removeControl`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$removeControl)

Answer (score 0):

Standard HTML doesn't allow nesting forms. Have a look at [ngForm](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm).

Comment: @With ng-form instead of form it's the same.